# Why is the performance so bad when I run multiple Android emulators?

Tags: android-emulator

I want to run multiple independent tasks on Android devices. To do so, I run the official Android emulator on an x86 machine. To start the machine, I use the command `emulator -avd <avd_device> -no-audio -no-window -skip-adb-auth -no-snapshot-save -wipe-data -no-boot-anim -gpu swiftshader_indirect`. The performance of the emulator is okay for my purpose.

Because the tasks that I want to run on the devices are independent, I want to parallelize and run multiple emulators at the same time. This, however, leads to a significant degradation of the performance across all emulators. So much that running one emulator is the faster option.

I monitored CPU utilisation, memory usage and I/O and this does not seem to be the bottleneck. Why does the performance still decrease? What other bottlenecks could there be?